# Retrofit call repeats to infinite and doesn't stop

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to make an API call with Retrofit 2.9.0 and use the response in a Jetpack Compose activity. The problem is that the call repeats to infinite and updates the UI on every frame. I have never used the retrofit library before so I'm sorry if the code is messy. I will attach a GIF with how the app behaves and code snippets for everything. Thanks for reading this and wanting to help. <3

[What is happening in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jazAr.gif)

Here is the class that makes the call to the API:

```
public class ApiHandler {

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.quotable.io/").build();
ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.getData();

public void getQuoteRaw()
{
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
             try {
                 MainActivityKt.getModel().setQuoteInfo(response.body().string());

           } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    });
}
```

The Interface I use to define the getData() method:

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET("random")
Call<ResponseBody> getData();
```

The ViewModel class for the Compose Activity:

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
var quoteInfo by mutableStateOf("")
```

The Jetpack Compose activity:

```
val model = MainViewModel()
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        QuoteappTheme {

            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                Greeting()
            }
        }
    }
}
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(viewModel: MainViewModel = model) {

val apihandle = ApiHandler()
apihandle.getQuoteRaw()
Text(text = viewModel.quoteInfo)
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
QuoteappTheme {
    Greeting()
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome here! To allow users understand and test your code; it's required to post it as text not image

Comment: Hello! is it ok if i edit the question and add the code snippets?

Comment: @Zain I have edited it. May you help me please?

Comment: I believe you should remove the "apihandle.getQuoteRaw()" in the "Greeting" function because it could be causing the repetitive rebuilding the UI due to state changes, try to add it in a button instead or call it in the "onCreate" when the app launches, I'm quite sure but try it!

Comment: devmuaz is right; Greeting should only update the UI

Comment: Thanks to @Zain, too. I could not mention you both in a comment.